# Bash script to backup new or modified files inside a directory

Tags: bash, incremental-backup

Does anyone have a bash script that will only backup new or modified files inside a specific directory?

Basically, what I'm looking for is an incremental backup. I've been running a full backup for a couple days now and it's just not practical.

Answer (score 3):

```
man rsync
```

it does exactly what you need

to be more specific - you must have `rsync --daemon` on the machine with the files and the following command on the machine the backup is stored

```
/usr/bin/rsync -avz 1.2.3.4::ETC/ /some/dir/to/store/the/backup
```

where 1.2.3.4 is the ip of the machine and ETC is defined in /etc/rsyncd.conf as seen below

```
[ETC]
        comment = etc
        path = /etc
        use chroot = yes
        list = no
        uid = 0
        gid = 0
        read only = yes
        hosts allow = 6.7.8.9, 10.11.12.13
        hosts deny = 0.0.0.0/0
        transfer logging = yes
```

also, port 873/tcp must be allowed in the firewall

Comment: http://www.mikerubel.org/computers/rsync_snapshots/

Comment: If you have SSH access to the other box, you don't *need* rsync --daemon on the other end. Just rsync -avz mylocaldir remoteuser@remotehost:backupDir is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest [rsnapshot](http://rsnapshot.org/howto/).

Answer (score 0):

[rdiff-backup](http://rdiff-backup.nongnu.org/) is honestly your best bet for this. I've been using it for about 2 years on a fairly large and active box. Using it is pretty straight forward:

```
rdiff-backup /my_active_dir /my_backup_dir/
```

If you're interested in backups over a network, check out Duplcity (Google for it, I can't post two links apparently) which works under the same concept but sends encrypted volumes to wherever you wish. Even supports Amazon S3.

Answer (score -1):

rsync cannot create incremental backups. Try [rdiff-backup](http://is.gd/4zbrb).

Comment: That's not what `man rsync` suggests. See the `--backup-dir=DIR` option.

Comment: that's why some people use tools which come with the distro, and others use third-party apps/scripts/etc - the patience to read manpages :)